# Why doesn't Google Plus pick up link description?

Tags: google-plus

When I paste a link into a Google Plus post (using the link option), the title and image appear but there is no description.  I've noticed this on many links but some do display a description.  I'm not sure what the difference is.

The links I'm trying are formatted for OpenGraph and work fine on Facebook.  I understand that g+ should pick up this info as well.  But it doesn't for description.

Any ideas on a fix?

Comment: Do you have some example links where this happens?

Comment: Even with schema.org, og:description and meta description, I'm still not seeing a description show up. I assume google plus sharer either bugged, or just outright ignores it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Google+ stopped including the description when posting

I did not find any official place where they confirmed this

I tried using schema, open graph and meta description - all failed

Comment: For what it's worth, [this tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets) from Google successfully reads all Schema.org and HTML meta tags on my page, but G+ does not display a description when sharing the link, to confirm your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Although the Google+ bot does generally pick up OpenGraph markup, it often gets it wrong, or interprets it slightly differently than Facebook does. Your safest bet is to also include schema.org snippet data in addition to the OpenGraph information.

Comment: For a Wordpress blog, is there an efficient way to do that?